Understanding "um...zu" in a Sentence Formation
I'm trying to understand the formation of "um...zu" in the below question and also find the answer to the question:
Bei der Zettel-Masche wird das Opfer durch ein Gespräch abgelenkt,

um eine Nachricht für den Nachbarn zu übergeben.
um dem Komplizen Zeit zu geben.
um zu erfahren, wo Wertgegenstände in der Wohnung sind.

The correct answer is (2) but not (3). Please explain why (2) is correct and why isn't (3) the correct answer?
Paragraph for Context:

Eine weitere beliebte Masche ist der Zettel-Trick. Wiederum das Klingeln an der Haustür, zwei fremde
Menschen stehen im Hausflur, einer der beiden bittet um einen Zettel
und einen Stift, um dem Nachbarn eine Nachricht zu hinterlassen.
Während das Opfer einen Zettel holt, lenkt einer der Täter weiterhin
ab, indem er das Opfer in ein Gespräch verwickelt oder ein Geschenk
für den Nachbarn präsentiert. Diese Zeit der Unaufmerksamkeit nutzt
der Komplize und durchsucht blitzschnell die Wohnung nach
Wertgegenständen.

From what I understand, the subject should be the same in both the main clause and the "um...zu" clause. So far, I have not come across examples of "um...zu" with passive. Can you help me understand these formations in passive and eventually find the answer? (Proabably, it would help if you could rewrite these sentences using "damit")

It is not clear what your question is about. Is it about the "um .. zu" clause in the quoted paragraph, the "um .. zu" clauses in the answers or which answer of the 3 answers is correct. Please clarify.

Having read your question again, it is now clear to me that it's about the "um .. zu" in the answers. But how this relates to why (2) is correct and not (3) is still not clear. What's more, it's not clear what this has to do with the main clause being in passive. Frankly, your question is very confusing.

Thank you for the comment, I will update the question to make it clear :)

It is actually both. Helping me understand the um..zu formation with those examples might help me finding the answer or the other way round, would work!

Let's look at the correct answer:

Bei der Zettel-Masche wird das Opfer durch ein Gespräch abgelenkt, um dem Komplizen Zeit zu geben.

This can be translated to the follwing sentence while preserving the general structure:
In the "Zettel-Masche" ("note scam"), the victim is distracted by a conversation in order to give the accomplice time.
So the infinitive clause tells us what the purpose of the action in the main clause is. When the main clause is in passive voice, it is not the grammatical subject of the main clause but the actor of the main clause (the one who talks to the victim) which is also the (implied) subject of the infinitive clause.
Now in the text we find the sentence "Diese Zeit der Unaufmerksamkeit nutzt der Komplize und durchsucht blitzschnell die Wohnung nach Wertgegenständen."
This sentence tells us that the accomplice uses the time during which the victim is distracted to search the flat for valuable things. This conforms to what answer 2) states which is why this answer is the correct one.

This is all about the workings of the scam.

suggests that asking for pen and paper gives the scammers information about the valueables. But it doesn't. It's not very likely that you have pen and paper at the same place as your nest egg.

So it's about gaining time.

This answer is correct with respect to what the correct answer is but there is no relation to the "um .. zu" construction mentioned in the question. But what the "um .. zu" has to do with the correct answer is not clear anyway which is why I asked for clarification.

Thank you :) Could you please translate that exact meaning? DeepL provides this translation for the 3rd option - In the note scam, the victim is distracted by a conversation in order to find out where valuables are in the home.

That translation is correct for the third option. You can almost always translate um … zu with in order to. The second option hence should be translated as In the note scam, the victim is distracted in order to gain time to search the home.
